# Why are the Emitter functions not working?

Tags: rec-room

I can no longer turn off the emitter from working. I cannot adjust the size of the emission. Is this a known bug? I have tried setting the default size value from 0 to 100, the emit to 0 or above. No effect. I have tried using a variable chip to do the same. No effect.

Comment: Please do one of the following for all your questions: 1. Accept an answer if your question has been answered. 2. If the existing answers are not sufficient, add a comment to them what you are missing. 3. If your question is no longer relevant, delete it. That way we can keep track of questions that still need attention

Answer (score 1):

To be able to control an emitter through the circuit pins, you first have to disable the "Looping?" checkbox in the configuration of the emitter. Not doing so makes the emitter ignore the on/off circuit input.